# I dont find the lxss directory within my C:/Users/UsernameAppData/Local directory

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to look into the files of the Windows Ubuntu Subsystem. But I don't find the lxss folder under the Local directory. I even changed the options allowing "Show hidden files" for the directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directory `C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Local\lxss` is not visible because it is a **Protected Operating System** folder (just like *System Volume Information* or *$Recycle.Bin* in C: directory is).

Best way to access the **lxss** folder is to paste `C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Local\lxss` in address bar (or whatever it is called) of the Explorer and hit Enter. Alternatively, you can open **Folder Options**, go to **View** tab and uncheck **Hide Protected Operating System Files** options, but that's not recommended.

Comment: this is no longer the correct answer @Josephine, the right answer is below C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\rootfs\

Comment: there is no *lxss* in my case. windows came up with a stupid update that deleted microsoft office. so i tried a system restore and it hung at registry part so i forced restart and now i also lost the Ubuntu app. is that the reason i don't see *lxss*?

Answer (score 5):

It was actually moved in the latest release to :

`C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\rootfs\`

See [this blog post from WLS git repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/2578)